# Issue installing Ubuntu 14.10 over 6 on older HP Pavilion tower

Tags: 14.10, hp, dvd

I have an hp pavilion desktop. got a CD/book from the library and was able to install Ubuntu 6. I deleted the Windows XP intentionally (tried the 6.0 demo and liked) and then upgrade through each version to the current one. Had issues with upgrading (certain files not found, etc.) so bought a disc of 14.10 (32 bit) from Amazon.

DVD is not being recognized though. System either boots up to the existing 6.0 on the computer or the system just sits with a black screen, cursor flashing in upper left, and the DVD drive blinks. Have let it run an hour like that. Machine is set to boot from DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have your BIOS set to boot from CD-ROM before it attempts to boot from the hard drive. Then you should be fine. If all else fails just nuke the hard drive (that is what I had to do on my desktop because GRUB was being difficult).

Get Nuke Here: http://www.dban.org/download (Just get DBAN not the premium)